# Excel nested IF statement

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested-if

```
=If(ISBLANK(F3),IF(F3<E3, ʺYesʺ, ʺNoʺ))
```

Have tried many iterations of this code to reach two outcomes on a stock order sheet.

Result should return If Blank or cell difference is equal or greater than as 
"Yes" and "No" if smaller than.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the error message really **Parse Error**?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Me no think so!

Comment: @Forwarded I'd be surprised if it were, too.  But I've been surprised in the past :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using ISBLANK(), use the following:

```
=IF(OR(F3="",F3>=E3),"No","Yes")
```

You have two options there as your question was not clear as to which cell was to be greater than or equal which.

The reason you want to use the F3="" instead of ISBLANK(F3), is that if you have a formula in F3 that returns "" as a result, that is not the same as a blank cell.  If you want to be safer, you may want to consider wrapping the first F3 in a CLEAN(TRIM(F3)) to remove when someone may have entered a space in the cell.

Comment: Base Stock Level Quantity in Stock Need to order Quantity to order  are the headings so basically if the quantity in stock is less than the base stock level the need to order cell should read yes or no and also no if the cell is empty.

Comment: So when you have a value in E and a Value in F, does E need to be less than F or does F need to be less than E for no to display?

Comment: E needs to be less than or equal to F

Comment: Formula has been updated.  If you look at the OR( , )  there is a logical check before and after the coma.  If either of those logical checks is TRUE, then the whole OR() is equal to TRUE.  And when the OR is TRUE, then you get a NO.

Comment: Thank you so much! Lifesaver!

Answer (score 2):

Check your quotes. Excel uses simple quotes " not ʺ.

```
=If(ISBLANK(F3),IF(F3<E3, "Yes", "No"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(F13),F13<E13),"No","Yes")
```